# Postgresql select from where

Tags: postgresql

I would like to look up records based on column value.

I know how to do this using the select from where command.

However I am facing an issue with the value of the column I would like to lookup values for.

The problem is that the value has a / in it.

So here is the command:

```
SELECT COLA FROM TABLENAME WHERE COLB = cotton/candy;
```

This is giving me an issue as column "cotton" does not exist.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance and best regards,

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap the value in quotes this should work since it will look for an exact string match:

```
SELECT COLA FROM TABLENAME WHERE COLB = 'cotton/candy';
```

Answer (score 1):

The content of the value should not matter at all.

Your syntax is invalid either with, or without, the `/`.

```
COLB = cotton/candy;
```

is just as wrong as

```
COLB = cotton;
```

since in neither case do you use `'quotes for literals'`.

There's a broader problem though. Say you write:

```
COLB = '$1'
```

where `$1` is some program variable substitution. Then someone sends the value `');DROP TABLE COLA;--`. Whoops! They ran a command on your DB and dropped your table. This is called [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and to avoid it, you should make sure to use bind parameters ("parameterised statements", "prepared statements") for *all* user-supplied or interpolated values in your queries.

Comment: Do you have a link of security topics for web enterprise applications.